# Why this code below doesnt show the expected result

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i was working on a digital clock with HTML/CSS/JS but for some reason it doesnt work the way i expected it to.Any suggetions?  Thank's in advance!
It work's fine on the snippet but when i try to open it in my browser i just see  a black background....

```js
function startTime(){
  var date = new Date()
  var h = date.getHours() // 0 - 23
  var m = date.getMinutes() // 0 - 59
  var s = date.getSeconds() // 0 - 59
  var session = "AM"

  if (h == 0){
    h = 12
  }

  if (h > 12){
    h = h - 12 
    session = "PM"
  }

  h = (h < 10)? "0" + h : h
  m = (m < 10)? "0" + m : m
  s = (s < 10)? "0" + s : s
   
  var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session
  document.getElementById("digclock").innerHTML = time
  document.getElementById("digclock").textContent = time

  setTimeout(startTime, 1000) //1000ms = 1sec
}

startTime()
```

```css
    body {
    background: black;
}

.clock {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    color: #17D4FE;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: Orbitron;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clock" id="digclock" onload="startTime()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since your JS isn't changing the color, where is your CSS? We can't help without that.

Comment: I pushed the code in a parsable snippet and it runs just fine there. What problem do you exactly have. what is not working as intended?

Comment: Why are you assigning both `innerHTML` and `textContent`? The second will override the first.

Comment: Hey @tacoshy i dont know why but in the snippet it work's fine.W hen i open it on my browser i just see a black background

Comment: I would start by adding semicolons where appropriate.  Expect unexpected results when excluding basic syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the snippet below, I added the CSS for the task you wanted. the background color is black because of `body { background-color: black; }`.
To have the clock colored in rgeen you use `{ color: green; }`. Then I vertically and horizontally centered the clock with a wrapper as shown in the snippet.

```js
function startTime(){
  var date = new Date();
  var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
  var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
  var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
  var session = "AM";

  if (h == 0){
    h = 12;
  }

  if (h > 12){
    h = h - 12; 
    session = "PM";
  }

  h = (h < 10)? "0" + h : h;
  m = (m < 10)? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10)? "0" + s : s;
   
  var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
  document.getElementById("digclock").innerHTML = time;
  document.getElementById("digclock").textContent = time;

  setTimeout(startTime, 1000); //1000ms = 1sec
}

startTime();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  height: calc(100vh - 1em);
  width: 100%;
}

.clock {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <div class="clock" id="digclock" onload="startTime()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @tacoshy thanks for taking the time to help me with my problem!In the snippet code it run's fine but in my browser when i open it i just see a black background any thought on that?

Comment: well for that you have to provide the css or at least a link to your website so it can be checked. Otherwise it is just guessing without any evidence.

Comment: i have provided the css code i updated my question @tacoshy but again it work's fine on the snippet not in my browser.... weird

Comment: in the updated code snippet, your css works fine too, could also be just a browser cachign issue. try to clear your cache of the browser then.

Comment: I cleared my browser cache still nothing :(

Comment: then like I said, you ahve to post a link to your website so we can see what you did wrong. Otherwise its just guessing into the blue.

Comment: How can i send you a link its not really on a website i just open the html file with chrome from my pc

Comment: i get this error 
main.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at startTime (main.js:22)
    at main.js:28

Comment: thats because of missing semicolons then; watch the JS for the semicolon placements. you have to end a command line with a semicolon.

Comment: It was because i was importing the script on the header BEFORE the div element so my script couldnt find the div element i put it after the body and it works fine